How to clean up thread-local data after using ThreadPoolExecutor?
I want to use ThreadPoolExecutor to parallelize some (legacy) code with database access. I would like to avoid creating a new database connection for each thread, so I use threading.local() to keep a single connection per thread, e.g.:
thread_local = threading.local()

def get_thread_db():
    if not hasattr(thread_local, "db"):
        thread_local.db = get_database_connection()
    return thread_local.db

def do_stuff():
    db_conn = get_thread_db()
    # ... 

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_stuff, *params) for params in data]
    # ...

How do I ensure that all threads' connections are properly closed after all the submitted tasks are finished? It appears that ThreadPoolExecutor has the initializer parameter, but no parameter for an exit handler.

I think you are asking the wrong question. If the question is "How to clean up thread-local data?" That might be a hard problem. But, if the question is, "How can my program close all of the database connections that it opened?" That might be an easier problem to solve.

@SolomonSlow Maybe. The current implementation uses thread-local storage to cache connections, thus the question. I'd appreciate any other working solution of comparable complexity.

I don't know how your database API works, but if it allows you to open a connection in one thread, and then close it in another thread after the first thread has terminated, then all you'd have to do is append each new connection to a  global list when you create it, Then after some other thread (e.g., the main thread) has shut down the thread pool, it could iterate over the list, and close each connection.

P.S., I can't answer the question about threading.local. I've never used thread-local variables in any programming language, and I'll write (have written actually) a lot of lines of code in order to avoid using them. Thread-local variables don't make any sense unless they also are static, global variables, and there's a lot of good reason to avoid using static, global variables in new code.

The general pattern I would follow for cleaning up thread local storage is to create a class that encapsulates the data (objects) needing cleaning up and has a __del__ method that would be invoked when the thread local data is garbage collected. This method would perform all the cleanup that is required.
In your specific case I would create a class, e.g. DB_Connection, that encapsulates a database connection as attribute _connection and its __del__ method would close the connection:
import concurrent.futures
import threading

thread_local = threading.local()

class DB_Connection:
    def __init__(self):
        self._connection = get_database_connection()
        
    def __del__(self):
        self._connection.close()
        
    @classmethod
    def get_thread_db(cls):
        if not hasattr(thread_local, "db"):
            thread_local.db = cls()
        return thread_local.db._connection
        

def do_stuff():
    db_conn = DB_Connection.get_thread_db()
    # ... 

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_stuff, *params) for params in data]
    # ...


Is the thread-local data actually garbage collected when a thread finishes execution? I couldn't find anything regarding this in the docs.

See this demo. Experience tells me this is so. If you want to be extra safe, you can add thread_local = None; import gc; gc.collect() when you are through.

Thread local data is local to a thread. When the thread terminates, its data is garbage collected. If you do not get warm and fuzzy feeling from this, I just asked ChatGPT if thread local storage is garbage collected and it confirms that it is without pointing to a specific URL. Note that I did not use this as the basis of my answer. See this 4-year old, pre-ChatGPT answer to a different problem that uses the same technique.

@Booboo to be fair using chatgpt for information only reduces an answer's creditability, instead you should point at the line in CPython's source code or documentation that states that, like this source code line which deletes the data when the thread object is destroyed, and AFAIK python threadpool joins their threads on destruction which means they will be deleted.

@AhmedAEK I was hoping that ChatGPT would be able to point to documentation that explicitly states that the local storage is deleted upon thread termination, but there was no such documentation it could find. It's actually line 176 that is key. The line reads: # When the thread is deleted, remove the local dict. By the way, I understand the problem to be the general question of how to clean up objects stored in thread local storage. Your answer doesn't really address that.

@Booboo Well, If thread-local data is guaranteed to be deleted when the thread exits, that should be enough in most cases. I suppose, any sane database access library would free up resources when related objects get garbage collected.

@EugeneYarmash Yes, a database connection is likely to be closed when it is garbage collected. But if we are looking for a general solution to cleaning up thread-local data, then in general you need to have a __del__ method that does the cleanup that would not otherwise be automatically done.

The other solution is to use a pool of connections instead of using thread-local storage. Each thread will either get a pooled connection or create a new one, then when its work is done it will put it back into the pool for the next thread.
This pool can be a simple queue.Queue, that you try to pull an item out of it when it is not empty.
Another advantage of this approach is that you can reuse connections in later transactions instead of creating new ones for each thread. (similar to the concept of reusing threads with a thread pool instead of creating a thread for each transaction).
import concurrent.futures
import queue
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Connection:
    pass

@contextmanager
def get_connection_from_pool(connections: queue.Queue):
    conn = None
    try:
        try:
            conn = connections.get_nowait()
            print("got old connection")
        except queue.Empty:
            conn = get_database_connection()
            print("got new connection")
        yield conn
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            connections.put(conn)

def get_database_connection():
    return Connection()

def do_stuff(connections: queue.Queue, *args):
    with get_connection_from_pool(connections) as db_conn:
        pass

connections = queue.Queue()

data = [(connections, x) for x in range(20)]
max_workers = 4
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    futures = [executor.submit(do_stuff, *params) for params in data]
for fut in futures:
    fut.result()

print(connections.qsize())

note: CPython Queue.get_no_wait actually waits for the queue lock, it only doesn't wait for new items to be added if the queue is empty, i can't say the same for other python implementations.
You should wrap both the queue and get_connection_from_pool in a class to make the API look better.
